# Recursively use of self-implemented cuIDFT.cu leads to changing output every time when re-runing the code

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu, dct, cufft

I have implemented a CUDA version of inverse discrete cosine transform (IDCT), by "translating" the MATLAB built-in function `idct.m` into CUDA:

- My implementation is `cuIDCT.cu`, works when *m = n* and both *m* and *n* are even numbers.

**cuIDCT.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>

// round up n/m
inline int iDivUp(int n, int m)
{
    return (n + m - 1) / m;
}

typedef cufftComplex complex;

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751

__global__
    void idct_ComputeWeightsKernel(const int n, complex *ww)
{
    const int pos = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (pos >= n) return;

    ww[pos].x =  sqrtf(2*n) * cosf(pos*PI/(2*n));
    ww[pos].y =  sqrtf(2*n) * sinf(pos*PI/(2*n));
}

__global__
    void idct_ComputeEvenKernel(const float *b, const int n, const int m, complex *ww, complex *y)
{
    const int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (ix >= n || iy >= m) return;

    const int pos = ix + iy*n;

    // Compute precorrection factor
    ww[0].x = ww[0].x / sqrtf(2);
    ww[0].y = ww[0].y / sqrtf(2);

    y[iy + ix*m].x = ww[iy].x * b[pos];
    y[iy + ix*m].y = ww[iy].y * b[pos];
}

__global__
    void Reordering_a0_Kernel(complex *y, const int n, const int m, complex *yy)
{
    const int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (ix >= n || iy >= m) return;

    const int pos = ix + iy*n;

    yy[iy + ix*n].x = y[pos].x / (float) n;
    yy[iy + ix*n].y = y[pos].y / (float) n;
}

__global__
    void Reordering_a_Kernel(complex *yy, const int n, const int m, float *a)
{
    const int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (ix >= n || iy >= m) return;

    const int pos = ix + iy*n;

    // Re-order elements of each column according to equations (5.93) and (5.94) in Jain
    if (iy < n/2)
    {
        a[ix + 2*iy*n]     = yy[pos].x;
        a[ix + (2*iy+1)*n] = yy[ix + (m-iy-1)*n].x;
    }
}

/**
* a = idct(b), where a is of size [n m].
* @param b, input array
* @param n, first dimension of a
* @param m, second dimension of a
* @param a, output array
*/
void cuIDCT(float *h_in, int n, int m, float *h_out) // a is of size [n m]
{
    const int data_size   = n * m * sizeof(float);

    // device memory allocation
    float *d_in, *d_out;
    cudaMalloc(&d_in, data_size);
    cudaMalloc(&d_out, data_size);

    // transfer data from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, data_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // compute IDCT using CUDA
    // begin============================================
    // Compute weights
    complex *ww;
    cudaMalloc(&ww, n*sizeof(complex));
    dim3 threads(256);
    dim3 blocks(iDivUp(n, threads.x));
    idct_ComputeWeightsKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(n, ww);

    complex *y;
    complex *yy;
    cufftHandle plan;

    dim3 threads1(32, 6);
    dim3 blocks2(iDivUp(n,   threads1.x), iDivUp(m, threads1.y)); // for even case

    int Length[1] = {m}; // for each IFFT, the length is m

    cudaMalloc(&y,  n*m*sizeof(complex));

    idct_ComputeEvenKernel<<<blocks2, threads1>>>(d_in, n, m, ww, y);

    cufftPlanMany(&plan, 1, Length, 
                 Length, 1, m, 
                 Length, 1, m, CUFFT_C2C, n);
    cufftExecC2C(plan, y, y, CUFFT_INVERSE); // y is of size [n m]

    cudaMalloc(&yy,  n*m*sizeof(complex));
    Reordering_a0_Kernel<<<blocks2, threads1>>>(y, n, m, yy);
    Reordering_a_Kernel<<<blocks2, threads1>>>(yy, n, m, d_out);
    // end============================================

    // transfer result from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, data_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // cleanup
    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(ww);
    cudaFree(y);
    cudaFree(yy);
    cudaFree(d_in);
    cudaFree(d_out);
}
```

Then I compared the result of my CUDA IDCT (i.e. `cuIDCT.cu`) against MATLAB `idct.m` using following code:

- a test `main.cpp` function, and
- a MATLAB main function `main.m` to read result from CUDA and compare it against MATLAB.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <helper_functions.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// N must equal to M, and both must be even numbers
#define N 256
#define M 256

void WriteDataFile(const char *name, int w, int h, const float *in, const float *out)
{
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fopen(name, "wb");

    float data = 202021.25f;
    fwrite(&data, sizeof(float), 1, stream);
    fwrite(&w,    sizeof(w), 1, stream);
    fwrite(&h,    sizeof(h), 1, stream);

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            const int pos = j + i * h;
            fwrite(in  + pos, sizeof(float),  1, stream);
            fwrite(out + pos, sizeof(float), 1, stream);
        }

    fclose(stream);
}

void cuIDCT(float *b, int n, int m, float *a);

int main()
{
    // host memory allocation
    float *h_in   = new float [N * M];
    float *h_out  = new float [N * M];
    float *h_temp = new float [N * M];

    // input data initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < N * M; i++)
    {
        h_in[i]   = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_out[i]  = h_in[i];
        h_temp[i] = h_in[i];
    }

    // please comment either one case for testing
    // test case 1: use cuIDCT.cu once
    // cuIDCT(h_in, N, M, h_out);

    // test case 2: iteratively use cuIDCT.cu
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            cuIDCT(h_out, N, M, h_temp);
        else
            cuIDCT(h_temp, N, M, h_out);
    }

    // write data, for further visualization using MATLAB
    WriteDataFile("test.flo", N, M, h_in, h_out);

    // cleanup
    delete [] h_in;
    delete [] h_out;
    delete [] h_temp;
    cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

**main.m**

```
clc;clear;

% read
[h_in, h_out] = read_data('test.flo');

% MATLAB result, for test case 1, comment the for-loop
matlab_out = h_in;
for i = 1:4
    matlab_out = idct(matlab_out);
end

% compare
err = matlab_out - h_out;

% show
figure(1);
subplot(221);   imshow(h_in,  []);       title('h\_in');        colorbar
subplot(222);   imshow(h_out, []);       title('h\_out');       colorbar
subplot(223);   imshow(matlab_out, []);  title('matlab\_out');  colorbar
subplot(224);   imshow(err,   []);       title('error map');    colorbar

disp(['maximum error between CUDA and MATLAB is ' ...
        num2str(max(max(abs(err))))])
```

I ran the code on Visual Studio 11 (i.e. VS2012) in Windows 7 with Nvidia GPU Tesla K20c, using CUDA Toolkit version 7.5, and my MATLAB version is R2015b.

**My test steps**:

- **For test case 1**. Un-comment test case 1 and comment test case 2.

  1. Run `main.cpp`.
  2. Run `main.m` in MATLAB.
  3. Repeat step 1 and step 2 (without any change, just re-run the code).

I repeated step 3 for 20 times. The output result is unchanged, and results in `main.m` are:

[results of test case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgDuZ.png)

The maximum error is 7.7152e-07.

- **For test case 2**. Un-comment test case 2 and comment test case 1.

  1. Run `main.cpp`.
  2. Run `main.m` in MATLAB.
  3. Repeat step 1 and step 2 (without any change, just re-run the code).

I repeated step 3 for 20 times. The output result is changed, and results in `main.m` are (*not enough reputation to put all images, only wrong case is shown below*):

[one situation (the wrong one) of test case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwSYZ.png)

The maximum error is 0.45341 (2 times), 0.44898 (1 time), 0.26186 (1 time), 0.26301 (1 time), and 9.5716e-07 (15 times).

From the test results, **my conclusion** is:

- From test case 1: `cuIDCT.cu` is numerically correct (error ~10^-7) to `idct.m`.
- From test case 2: recursively use of `cuIDCT.cu` leads to unstable result (i.e. the output changes every time when re-run the code and may sometimes be numerically wrong, error ~0.1)

**My question:**

From test case 1 we know `cuIDCT.cu` is numerically correct to `idct.m`. But why recursiviely use of `cuIDCT.cu` leads to different output result each time when re-run the code?

Any helps or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: One of your claims is variability run-to-run in test case 2.  I'm unable to reproduce that.  As a test, I added a `double din = 0.0; double dout = 0.0;` before the for-loops in your `WriteDataFile` function.  In the body of the loops I created a checksum using `din += in[pos]; dout += out[pos];`.  After the for loops, I print those quantities out.  They are unchanged run-to-run.  I don't think your CUDA code is displaying any variability run-to-run.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/VtYmcxux) is my full test case.  As an error-check  you might want to try running your code with `cuda-memcheck`.

Comment: Perhaps there might be variability if you are occasionally (1 out of 4 times) hitting a WDDM TDR timeout, since you are on windows.  This seems unlikely to me but it would be good to rule it out.  You should add [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code. (`cuda-memcheck` will slow execution down) Finally, are you building a debug project or a release project in VS?  Are you building a win32 project or a x64 project in VS?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I revised my code according to your suggestions as [here](http://pastebin.com/3WznVxCa), added (a) `checkCudaErrors` and (b) `cufftSafeCall` and (c) your `din` and `dout`. I ran the code in VS using "Debug -> Start Debugging (F5)" each time. And the results in the previous link was obtained using "Debug -> Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5)" each time, output was recorded manually. It took VS a long time for the first run, but much faster in subsequent runnings. From "Property Pages" it is shown "Platform: Active(x64)". So I am guessing I am building a debug x64 project in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the variability in your results is coming about due to this code in your `idct_ComputeEvenKernel`:

```
// Compute precorrection factor
ww[0].x = ww[0].x / sqrtf(2);
ww[0].y = ww[0].y / sqrtf(2);
```

It's not entirely clear what your intent is here, but it's doubtful that this code could be doing what you want.  You may be confused about the CUDA execution model.

The above code will be executed by *every* CUDA thread that you launch for that kernel that passes the thread check:

```
if (ix >= n || iy >= m) return;
```

I believe this means 65536 threads will all execute this code in that kernel.  Furthermore, the threads will execute that code in more-or-less any order (not all CUDA threads execute in lock-step).  They may even step on each other as they are trying to write out their values to the location `ww[0]`.  So the final result in `ww[0]` will be quite unpredictable.

When I comment out those lines of code, the results become stable for me (albeit different from what they were with those lines in place), unchanging from run to run.

I'd like to point something else out.  Wherever you are calculating the `.x` and `.y` values of a complex quantity, my suggestion would be to rework the code from this (for example):

```
y[iy + ix*m].x = ww[iy].x * b[pos];
y[iy + ix*m].y = ww[iy].y * b[pos];
```

to this:

```
complex temp1, temp2;
temp1 = ww[iy];
temp2.x = temp1.x * b[pos];
temp2.y = temp2.y * b[pos];
y[iy + ix*m] = temp2;
```

At least according to my testing, the compiler doesn't seem to be making this optimization for you, and one side-effect benefit is that it's much easier to test your code with `cuda-memcheck --tool initcheck ...`.  In the first realization, the compiler will load `y[iy + ix*m]` as an 8 byte quantity, modify either 4 or 8 bytes of it, then store `y[iy + ix*m]` as an 8 byte quantity.  The second realization should be more efficient (it eliminates the load of `y[]`), and eliminates the load of an uninitialized quantity (`y[]`), which the `cuda-memcheck` tool will report as a hazard.

This variability I'm describing should be possible whether you run either the 1-pass version of your code or the 4-pass version of your code.  Therefore I think your statements about the 1-pass version being correct are suspect.  I think if you run the 1-pass version enough, you will eventually see variability (although it may require varying initial memory conditions, or running on different GPU types).  Even in your own results, we see that 15 out of 20 runs of the 4 pass code produce "correct" results, i.e. the residual error is ~1e-7

Here's my modified `cuIDCT.cu` file, modified from the version you posted [here](http://pastebin.com/3WznVxCa).  The assumption I'm making below is that you wanted to compute the scaling on `ww[0]` only once, in which case we can easily handle that arithmetic as an addendum to the previous `idct_ComputeWeightsKernel`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include "assert.h"

// round up n/m
inline int iDivUp(int n, int m)
{
    return (n + m - 1) / m;
}

typedef cufftComplex complex;

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751

#define cufftSafeCall(err)      __cufftSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__)
inline void __cufftSafeCall(cufftResult err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if( CUFFT_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUFFT error in file '%s', line %d\n %s\nerror %d: %s\nterminating!\n",__FILE__, __LINE__,err, \
            _cudaGetErrorEnum(err)); \
            cudaDeviceReset(); assert(0); \
    }
}


__global__
    void idct_ComputeWeightsKernel(const int n, complex *ww)
{
    const int pos = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (pos >= n) return;
    complex temp;
    temp.x =  sqrtf(2*n) * cosf(pos*PI/(2*n));
    temp.y =  sqrtf(2*n) * sinf(pos*PI/(2*n));
    if (pos == 0) {
      temp.x /= sqrtf(2);
      temp.y /= sqrtf(2);}
    ww[pos] = temp;
}

__global__
    void idct_ComputeEvenKernel(const float *b, const int n, const int m, complex *ww, complex *y)
{
    const int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (ix >= n || iy >= m) return;

    const int pos = ix + iy*n;
/*  handle this in idct_ComputeWeightsKernel
    // Compute precorrection factor
    ww[0].x = ww[0].x / sqrtf(2);
    ww[0].y = ww[0].y / sqrtf(2);
*/
    complex temp1, temp2;
    temp1 = ww[iy];
    temp2.x = temp1.x * b[pos];
    temp2.y = temp1.y * b[pos];
    y[iy + ix*m] = temp2;
}

__global__
    void Reordering_a0_Kernel(complex *y, const int n, const int m, complex *yy)
{
    const int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (ix >= n || iy >= m) return;

    const int pos = ix + iy*n;
    complex temp1, temp2;
    temp1 = y[pos];
    temp2.x = temp1.x / (float) n;
    temp2.y = temp1.y / (float) n;
    yy[iy + ix*n] = temp2;
}

__global__
    void Reordering_a_Kernel(complex *yy, const int n, const int m, float *a)
{
    const int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    const int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (ix >= n || iy >= m) return;

    const int pos = ix + iy*n;

    // Re-order elements of each column according to equations (5.93) and (5.94) in Jain
    if (iy < n/2)
    {
        a[ix + 2*iy*n]     = yy[pos].x;
        a[ix + (2*iy+1)*n] = yy[ix + (m-iy-1)*n].x;
    }
}

/**
* a = idct(b), where a is of size [n m].
* @param b, input array
* @param n, first dimension of a
* @param m, second dimension of a
* @param a, output array
*/
void cuIDCT(float *h_in, int n, int m, float *h_out) // a is of size [n m]
{
    const int data_size   = n * m * sizeof(float);

    // device memory allocation
    float *d_in, *d_out;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_in,  data_size));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_out, data_size));

    // transfer data from host to device
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, data_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // compute IDCT using CUDA
    // begin============================================
    // Compute weights
    complex *ww;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&ww, n*sizeof(complex)));
    dim3 threads(256);
    dim3 blocks(iDivUp(n, threads.x));
    idct_ComputeWeightsKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(n, ww);

    complex *y;
    complex *yy;
    cufftHandle plan;

    dim3 threads1(32, 6);
    dim3 blocks2(iDivUp(n,   threads1.x), iDivUp(m, threads1.y)); // for even case

    int Length[1] = {m}; // for each IFFT, the length is m

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&y,  n*m*sizeof(complex)));

    idct_ComputeEvenKernel<<<blocks2, threads1>>>(d_in, n, m, ww, y);
    cufftSafeCall(cufftPlanMany(&plan, 1, Length,
                                Length, 1, m,
                                Length, 1, m, CUFFT_C2C, n));
    cufftSafeCall(cufftExecC2C(plan, y, y, CUFFT_INVERSE)); // y is of size [n m]

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&yy,  n*m*sizeof(complex)));
    Reordering_a0_Kernel<<<blocks2, threads1>>>(y, n, m, yy);
    cudaMemset(d_out, 0, data_size);
    Reordering_a_Kernel<<<blocks2, threads1>>>(yy, n, m, d_out);
    // end============================================

    // transfer result from device to host
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, data_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


    // cleanup
    cufftDestroy(plan);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(ww));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(y));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(yy));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_in));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_out));
}
```

You'll note I threw an extra `cudaMemset` on `d_out` in there, because it helped me clean up an issue with `cuda-memcheck --tool initcheck ...`.  It shouldn't be necessary, you can delete it if you want.